# Return lists using csv reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

this is my code. it works fine if I print the variables but if i return them and try to print them somewhere else only the last element gets printed.

```
def train_data(fname):

    #load csv training files
    with open (fname) as train:
        reader = csv.DictReader(train, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            peptide=[row['peptide']]
            allele=[row['allele']]
            score=[row['score']]
            #print(peptide, score, allele)
    return [peptide, allele, score]
```

**This is my csv file:**

```
peptide score   allele  
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.190842    DRB1_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006301    DRB1_0301
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.066851    DRB1_0401
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006344    DRB1_0405
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.035130    DRB1_0701
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006288    DRB1_0802
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.176268    DRB1_0901
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.042555    DRB1_1101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.114855    DRB1_1302
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006377    DRB1_1501
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006296    DRB3_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006313    DRB4_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.070413    DRB5_0101
```

I'm tryin to print it like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
   p, a, s = train_data('sample.txt')
   print(s)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you expect the output to look like. Alvaro's answer made me realize you may want to return three lists rather than one list (where each element is a list of three elements). Giving an example of what you expect to see would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make **peptide, allele, score** visible outside the `With` scope otherwise you will always get `[None,None,None]` array:

```
 def train_data(fname):

    #load csv training files
    peptide= []
    allele= []
    score = []
    with open (fname) as train:
        reader = csv.DictReader(train, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            peptide.append(row['peptide'])
            allele.append(row['allele'])
            score.append(row['score'])

    return [peptide, allele, score]
```

I just guessing you want not `[row['allele']]` statement.

now will work!

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning one thing. Try putting things in a list and returning the list:

```
def train_data(fname):
    peptides = []
    alleles = []
    scores = []

    #load csv training files
    with open (fname) as train:
        reader = csv.DictReader(train, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            peptides.append(row['peptide'])
            alleles.append(row['allele'])
            scores.append(row['score'])

    return peptides, alleles, scores
```

**EDIT**

Based on your usage in `__main__`, I revised my code to return three different lists.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the variable **s** will only print the score variable.

Try:

```
print(p, a, s)
```

If you would like the output to look like the above csv file:

```
print(zip(p, a, s))
```